# Python - Local variable error where variable is an imported class

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I need to import game_state.py in in order to use a class in it called State in some other classes.
However, when I try to initialize a class attribute using State it says local variable referenced before assignment

```
from game_state import State
class Game:
   current_state: State
   name: str

   def __init__(self, is_p1_turn: bool) -> None:

     self.is_p1_turn = is_p1_turn
     self.current_state = State('Player 1', None, self) if self.is_p1_turn \
        else self.current_state = State('Player 2', None, self)
     self.name = self.__name__
```

the first `State('player1' None, self)` shows error msg:

```
local variable 'State' value not used
```

the second `State('Plyaer2' None, self)` shows another msg:

```
local variable might referenced &  unresolved reference 'State'
```

I know there's something wrong but just couldn't figure it out

Comment: What is this: `current_state: State` attempting to do?

Comment: so State is a class in game_state that has 3 arguments so it goes like State(A, B, C) im attempting to make self.current_state a State object

Comment: Don't try to use Pythons ternary expressions if you don't know the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment syntax is incorrect. The shorthand one line `if/else` looks like

```
some_value = 1 if is_true else 0
```

where `is_true` is something that can be evaluated as a `bool`, you're doing

```
some_value = 1 if is_true else self.some_value = 0
```

i.e. you're mixing the one line `if/else` syntax with the regular `if/else` syntax.

Comment: hahahha damn my brain is jammed after 6 hrs of coding. thanks